# How can I get Thunderbird to work with the messaging menu?

Tags: release-freya, wingpanel, notifications, thunderbird

I have installed elementary OS Freya and I replaced Geary with Mozilla Thunderbird. Is there a way to get notifications in the top panel when a new email arrives like it does by default with Geary?

Comment: hey not sure but you can try this https://addons.mozilla.org/thunderbird/tag/libnotify

Comment: Yes that did part of the job, a bubble appear when a new message arrives, but not show a (1) in the notification icon in the top bar.

Comment: It shows blue dot, and you will see inbox (NUMBER). correct?

Answer (score 1):

**Note**: The follwing instructions valid when you loginto your mail via thunderbird. Also this is the normal(default) behavior for thunderbird (also for geary). See note 2.

Instructions:

- Open Thunderbird.

  [image: Imgur]
- Enable the "Messaging Menu ...." and restart.

  [image: Imgur]

If you got any message,  the panel icon shows **blue** dot, like:

[image: Imgur]

**Note 2**:

AFAIK, thunderbird does not have a background service that will fetch mails and show indicator. You have to loginto your mail to get notifications.

Comment: Well I don't know what is going on in my system, but this was already enabled and still is not working :/

Comment: try: disable and re-enable.

Comment: btw you have to loginto your account first in thunderbird. @user3377450

Comment: I tried disable and re-enable, what account, my email account?

Comment: sorry, yeah- your email account :)

Comment: Yes without log in into my account, there is not incoming emails to show :)

Comment: yes, that is normal behavior for geary also (as you asked)  :)

Comment: Finally nailed it, I just had to install a package called thunderbird-gnome-support

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer, all I had to to was install a package called thunderbird-gnome-support that somehow was not installed by default.

Comment: Will you please provide screenshot or link to download :)

Comment: You mean the package? it is in the default ubuntu repositories, just sudo apt-get install thunderbird-gnome-support

Comment: Oh, well :) I will have a look =)

Answer (score 0):

For me the package '*thunderbird-gnome-support*' doesn't work and i doesn't know what this is actually doing.

My working solution >> Install the extension **[Enhanced Desktop Notifications](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/thunderbird/addon/enhanced-desktop-notifications/)**

It will send a message to 'notify-send' library.

[image]

Comment: Just found a another extension...maybe...a more better one! :) 
**Gnotifier** -- its configurable and also for Firefox!! \o/ 
But I will test this later...because my first solution is working fine atM.

https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/gnotifier/